# jQuery animate of an absolute positioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to get the polygon to animate with the sibling div. I am thinking it is not animating due to it being absolute positioned? Is there a way to get it to slide along with the sibling div?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzxmk5jp/2/

jQuery:

```
$('.one').on('click',function(){

    var width = $('.one').width(),
        parentWidth = $('.one').offsetParent().width(),
        percent = 100*width/parentWidth;

    if(percent < '34'){
        $('.one').animate({
            width:'66%'
        }, 1000),
        $('.one .svg-right-arrow').animate({
            left:'100%'
        }, 1000)
    }
     if(percent > '34'){
        $('.one').animate({
            width:'34%'
        }, 1000),
        $('.one .svg-right-arrow').animate({
            left:'100%'
        }, 1000)
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="one">
        <div class="one-inner"></div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="svg-right-arrow" viewBox="0 0 20 152" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet">
            <polygon points="0,0 0,152 20,76"></polygon>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are comparing numbers to strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake of thinking it was a `position:absolute` issue. The issue is the `overflow:hidden`, so here is what I fount out, adding `.css('overflow','visible');` to the end of the animation:

jQuery:

```
$('.one').on('click',function(){

     var width = $('.one').width(),
        parentWidth = $('.one').offsetParent().width(),
        percent = 100*width/parentWidth;

     if(percent < '34'){
        $('.one').animate({
            width:'66%'
        }, 1000).css('overflow','visible');
     }
     if(percent > '34'){
        $('.one').animate({
            width:'34%'
        }, 1000).css('overflow','visible');
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzxmk5jp/7/

Answer (score 1):

this has nothing to do with them moving together, your arrow is positioned outside of your box and when you use `.animate()` it hides the overflow content during the transition. You can make your `.one-inner` background color less width and keep the arrow inside your box to have it move together (**NOTE** you'll have to play with the spacing to make it look better, mine is a simple example to explain the behavior):

```
.one-inner{
   background-color:#ed7581;
   width:75%;
   height:370px;
}

.one .svg-right-arrow{
   position: absolute;
   left: 74%;
   top:0;
   z-index: 10;
   height:100%;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzxmk5jp/3/)